# Using If - Then Statements in Sharepoint

Tags: list, list-view, column

I'm not sure there's a way to do this or not. I'm pretty sure there is but I can't seem to figure out how to write the statement.

What we need to do is to make Column B required if you choose Condition 1 or 2 in Column A.

For Example:
If Column A says: Hello, Column B is now required.
If Column A says: Goodbye, Column B is now required.
If Column A says : Blue, Column B is not required.

Is there a way to do this using an If/Then Statement?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can not change field required property with if and then on some other column value.

You can use some javascript and CSS tricks to acheive this. But with simple if and then it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No easy way to handle this situation. If/Then will not work as you want.

To achieve what you want, you need to use JQuery to traverse the column names to check if they are Column A = goodbye  If so, hide the columns.

Here is an example which is near to your sitution, try this one.

http://webdevshareetc.blogspot.it/2012/06/sharepoint-2010-multilanguage-site-show.html

http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/jquery-disable-button/

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2011/10/20/sharepoint-lists-conditional-formatting-using-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx